# Is the closed subgroup of any semisimple linear algebraic group semisimple?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a semisimple linear algebraic group $/K$, with $K$ a field and $char K = 0$. Let $H \leq S$ be a closed subgroup $/K$.

> Is $H$ semisimple?

Comment: Welcome to MSE please explain what you have already thought of or tried and where you are stuck

Comment: @Gage I'm not too sure where to begin, to be honest. I feel the answer is no, but I'm very bad at finding counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. An algebraic group is semisimple when it has no nontrivial connected normal solvable subgroups. So a nontrivial connected solvable group cannot be semisimple. Certainly $S$ contains some nontrivial connected solvable subgroups..